# Update values of a column which are depending on other column present in the same DataFrame in python

Tags: python, dataframe, mapping, data-science

- *I am using python in jupyter notebook.*

A DataFrame(df) is given :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Grade': ['A','B','C','D','E','A','B'],'MArks':['100','','','70','','','']})


   Grade    MArks
0   A       100
1   B   
2   C   
3   D       70
4   E   
5   A   
6   B
```

Given dictionary name(**'scaling'**) is as follows :

```
scaling = {'A':100,'B':90,'C':80,'D':75,'E':70}
```

How to update column **"MArks"** as per the given '**scaling'**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is called mapping:

```
df.MArks = df.Grade.map(scaling)
```